# Writing own test in R (mean test)

Tags: r, stochastic

i need to write an own test in R with the help of the mean of a given test statistic of 2 given random variables X and Y which are unknown distributed.

I am given following code:

```
mean.test <- function(x, y, B=10000,
alternative=c("two.sided","less","greater"))
{

p.value <- 0
alternative <- match.arg(alternative)

s<-replicate(B, (mean(sample(c(x,y), B, replace=TRUE))-mean(sample(c(x,y), B, replace=TRUE)))) # random samples of test statistics
t <- mean(x) - mean(y) #teststatistics t    
p.value <- 2 * (1- pnorm(mean(s)))   #try to calculate p value 

data.name <- deparse(substitute(c(x,y)))
names(t) <- "difference in means"
zero <- 0
names(zero) <- "difference in means"
return(structure(list(statistic = t, p.value = p.value,
method = "mean test", data.name = data.name,
observed = c(x,y), alternative = alternative,
null.value = zero),
class = "htest"))
}
```

Where t is the mean of a random set of the variables X and Y substracted from each other. I am given some solution to some function calls, but i never get them.

For example following:

```
 set.seed(0)
 mean.test(rnorm(100,50,4),rnorm(100,51,5),alternative="less")
```

Should output:

```
mean test
data: c(rnorm(100, 50, 4), rnorm(100, 51, 5))
difference in means = -2.0224, p-value = 0.0011
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is less than 0
```

But it outputs:

```
mean test

data:  c(rnorm(100, 50, 4), rnorm(100, 51, 5))
difference in means = -0.68157, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is less than 0
```

I am sure that i am calculating the p value in a wrong way. Also the mean values substracted from each other are wrong for this example, but right for other examples of the excercise. I am really confused as how to calculate the p value. How do i calculate it?

Comment: Shouldn't your calculation of `p-value` depend on `alternative`?

Comment: I only know that it is calculated different when the alternative is set to less or greater. I simply do not know how.

Comment: What does your statistics book say? It is usually given fairly explicitly. You need to understand a test before you try to implement it in code. For example -- shouldn't the variance play a role?

Comment: My statistics book says p-value is calculated with quantile() if H0 is met and if the alternative is met then it is calculated like p-value=2*(1-F_(N(0,1))(abs(T(X, Y))). I already implemented this but it doesn´t work as you can see, where F_(N(0,1)) is the standard distribution function and T(X, Y) the test statistics.

Comment: I think that your test statistic is wrong. It is too simple. Shouldn't it involve an estimate of the common variance (e.g. pooled variance) or some sort of estimate of standard error? What you have almost works in the case where the variance of both distributions is assumed to be 1.

Comment: `mean(sample(c(x,y),1000,TRUE))-mean(sample(c(x, y),2000,TRUE))` Is given to calculate a single test statistic. x and y are random variables defined as rnorm(n, k, p)

Comment: You can't ignore variance (either known or estimated from samples). Look at the following link. You seem to be missing the relevant denominator in your test statistic: http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/meancomp.htm

Comment: Thank you. I simply do not have the values of the needed parameters.

Comment: Your `s` suggests that you are doing some sort of resampling test (rather than a parametric test performed directly on `x` and `y` -- but then why compute your `t` at all?). Thus the link I gave isn't directly relevant, but you do need to do some sort of normalization so that under the null hypothesis your test statistic is standard normal (or at least approximately so). If you could find a link to a description of the test you are trying to implement, that would help.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `t.test`? Try `t.test(rnorm(100,50,4),rnorm(100,51,5),alternative="less")`

Comment: @ChiPak This seems to be a homework project for R programming rather than a practical statistical test. As such, it is a reasonable exercise.

Comment: Yes it is a homework project. The exercise says that i need to calculate the p-value with the replicated test statistics if H0 is true.